# BroadcastReceiver for incoming calls?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want a `BroadcastReceiver` for incoming calls.
I have searched about this on Stackoverflow and have read the answers but it does not log when Android device starts ringing. Here is my code -

```
 public class Mybrd extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 Log.i("LOG", "LOG ME");

 }
 }
```

manifest:

```
  <receiver android:name=".Mybrd">

 <intent-filter>

 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

 <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />

 </intent-filter> 

</receiver>
```

Comment: Show the permissions, you added in the manifest

Comment: okay...looks fine....what error are you getting, btw?

Comment: <pre> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/><code>

Comment: Please edit your question and post the full AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: no error but i do not get any log when phone ringing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you have register receiver correctly in manifest file.Please register recevier with fully qualified package name if it is not in the root package.

Comment: i added my full package name and it worked: <receiver android:name="com.mypackage.Mybrd">

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String phoneState =intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
 Log.i("LOG", "LOG ME");}}
```

Try using the above code. Add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```